# how to install jshint without internet connection

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install, jshint

I use a vscode and our company is unable to connect to the internet due to security concerns. However, I want to use the `jshint extension`.

So, I made the `jshint extension` to `.vsix`, moved it to my company computer and installed it and it says `npm install jshint.`

As far as I know, `npm` is only available on Internet. So I looked again and found that there was `npmbox`.

> https://serverfault.com/questions/559032/offline-install-of-npm-package

I created `jshint.npmbox` and istalled it as `npmunbox`.
This time I got **`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`** error.

Can not `jshint` be installed in an offline environment? Is there no way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use,
[Javascript Lint](http://javascriptlint.com/)
 which is available for offline usage. Hope, it is exactly providing similar support as jshint.

If you still want only jshint , then you may try forking [jshint from github](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) and try using it.